# Xamarin.Forms' Main Thread is single?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making an app with using XF pcl.

I'm curious its main thread is a single thread on both `iOS/Android` platforms. Because I faced this error rarely on `XF/Android`.

When I try to access myarray[i], I faced this rarely on `XF/Android`.

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]

I believe *Clean()* and *Update()* both are called from Main Thread, so it can't occur or am I wrong?

**Code**

```
IList<MyData> myarray = new List<MyData>();

void Clean() //when ContentPage is popped.
{
    ....
    StopMyTimer();
    myarray.Clear();
    myarray = null;
}

void Update() //every 50ms by Device.StartTimer
{
    ....
    if(myarray != null)
    {
        for(int i = myarray.Count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            MyData = myarray[i];
            if(/*needdelete*/)
                myarray.remove(MyData);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: try InvokeOnMainThread ( () => { // manipulate UI controls }); – Mike Darwish just now   edit

Comment: @MikeDarwish Hi, as I wrote, I'm sure it's been called from Main Thread. Then it's not needed, isnt it?

Comment: if you have sure, you did not need it

Comment: @MikeDarwish Yes. That's why I wrote a question..

Comment: did you face same issue  on IOS ?!

Comment: @MikeDarwish No. I faced it only on Android.

Comment: so, I think it is MainThread Issue :(

Comment: Looks like maybe your loop is giving up control, possibly because of setting MyData (does this raise a property changed event?) you may want to put in some debug logging to get a better idea of what is going on

Comment: @BillReiss No it does not raise a property changed event. I also want to see debug logging but it's very hard to reproduce. Actually, I couldn't see it but the crash tool(raygun) reported it. Can you tell more about "giving up control"? I couldn't understand clearly.

Comment: Sure, just because multiple things are running in a single thread, it doesn't mean that one will necessarily wait for the other to complete. For example, if you did some asynchronous file i/o on the UI thread, while the i/o is going on, other tasks would execute on the UI thread like updating the screen.

Comment: @BillReiss Hi bill, It does work like that? I though if it was the single thread, it would work like "one will necessarily wait for the other to complete".

Comment: @BillReiss Thanks for your answer. So, even if those two methods are invoked from the main thread, it might cause a problem. right?